# How can i see candle length on chart through pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I want to see the length of every candle on the chart through pine-script I don't know how to write pine-script please help me out

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

you can plot candle length by using below function

```
plot(high-low)
```